# RF signal identification algorithms

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, algorithms

There exist [many](https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Signal_Identification_Guide), [many](https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Database) analog and digital data transmission protocols. It is often difficult to tell which mode one listens to and tedious to do for many signals.

In Ham Radio, a [Reed-Solomon Identifier](http://www.w1hkj.com/RSID_description.html) may precede the signal, but this is not the case for every signal in existence.

Are there *algorithms* that automate the detection and mode differentiation from raw signal data that don't include metadata such as RSIDs?

Comment: Plenty! In fact, since the mid-1970s, people in security have been working on automatic transmission classification. It's a hard problem, and you logically can't detect *all* transmission schemes, but it's something that's being sold as service and as product, especially for government (and three-letter government agencies). [These guys](https://procitec.de/en/products/), for example, focus on HF/VHF/UHF comms, and I've seen the list of classifiable transmission schemes they had for a public demo. It's long.

Comment: If you are looking for something to read, perhaps [here](https://cyclostationary.blog/2017/01/16/modulation-recognition-using-cyclic-cumulants-part-i-problem-description-and-variants/) will be a good starting point.

Comment: "Automatic modulation recognition of communication signals" by Elsayed Elsayed Azzouz and Asoke Kumar Nandi is one of the classic references.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty! In fact, since the mid-1970s, people in security have been working on automatic transmission classification.
It's a hard problem, and you logically can't detect all transmission schemes, but it's something that's being sold as service and as product, especially for government (and three-letter government agencies).

[These guys](https://procitec.de/en/products/), for example, focus on HF/VHF/UHF comms, and I've seen the list of classifiable transmission schemes they had for a public demo. It's long.

Now, what these recognize are just common *standards* (in Ham Radio, that would be called *modes*),  and they are specific to one greater usage scenario (security-relevant communication).

There's a lot of underlying algorithms to automatically classify the number of observed channels, bandwidths, symbol rates, constellations, spreading, scramblers, error-correction codes, frame lengths, synchronization preambles.... but even listing these would take a book.

I can point you to what a student did during Google summer of code: It's [`gr-inspector`](https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-inspector/tree/maint-3.8), a GNU Radio-based signal detection and classification program.

[image: gr-inspector GUI]

It's pretty generic in that it detects *bands* with power in them (which is no good for spread-spectrum systems, but for anything else it's a viable approach), and it gets pretty specific once you have an OFDM signal in there. Part of his job was [writing a classifier](https://grinspector.wordpress.com/2016/07/08/week-7-ofdm-prototype/) just to get OFDM parameters: carriers, spacing, length of cyclic prefix. That took someone who was dangerously close to being a M.Sc. in communications engineering nearly 3 months. You can imagine how much work it is writing a set of classifiers for *all* useful transmission schemes!

You might be interested in the two papers he cites in his blogpost I linked to above; and especially their references.

Comment: Amazing! So, "Modulation Recognition" was the magic word. Thank you @Marcus Müller and @AnonSubmitter85! (I'll leave the answer unaccepted for now because maybe some people expand on this, refer to specific algorithms etc.)